# Matching any cell in one Cell Range with any cell another Cell Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
     Col A     |  Col B    |     Col C    |   Col D |       Col E     |
row1 Roles     |    Create |    Review    | Approve |      Name       |
row2 PM/Dev/IT |     SQA   |   PM/Dev/IT  |  SQA*   |    Ryan (IT)    |
     PM/Dev    |     SQA   |      N/A     |  SQA    |    Casey (SQA)  |
     PM        |     DEV   |       IT     |  PM     |    Shannon (PM) |
     DEV       |        
     IT        |            
     QA        |            
     SQA       |            
row8 SQA*      |                
rw9  SQA**     |                
     Other____ |

rw12 PM        |     CellB13=IF((A13=B2:D2), F4, "N/A")    |        
     SQA       |     CellB14=IF((A13=B2:D2), F5, "N/A")    |
rw13 IT        |     CellB15=IF((A13=B2:D2), F6, "N/A")    |
```

I want B13 = YES if

If the Role Column is in the Create/Review/orApprove row then display the PM value B13/B14/B15 show the Name Value in the corresponding cell

I want to avoid using VBA for a solution

Comment: B7:D7 comprises just 3 cells. Can you clarify which are the entries in each cell from the list you give (which seems to consist of 4, not 3), i.e. SQA, PM, DEV, IT?

Comment: Also, when you mention "partial" matching, are you aware that your definition will mean that, for example, an entry in the First Range of PM/DEV/BITE will still register as a "match" with IT from your Second Range, since IT is contained within BITE? If this is something you would not wish, you will have to be a bit clearer about what precisely constitutes a "match" here.

Comment: I take it you want to have no partial results in other cells? It would make things somewhat easier, and hiding columns could solve the problem.

Comment: My First range are the following, and if and of the 3 values in 2nd range match partially then yes                                                             PM/Dev/IT
PM/Dev
PM
DEV
IT
QA
SQA
SQA*
SQA**
Other
N/A

Comment: I can[t work out which of those values is in which cells. And you have yet to answer my other question re partial matching (cf my "BITE" example).

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to post examples in the forum, let me try to lay it out in my original post

Comment: I have updated the problem I still need to resolve

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the 'cell' layout by adding 'pipes' to define the column and the rw to define the rows. I wish there was a way to upload a file into the forum, for someone to review. It is difficult to describe the permutation match.  But example If 'IT' is in a cell by itself or included as part of the cell (eg . SQA/IT/DEV value), then I want the Row 13 IT B13 cell to show the Row 2/Col E name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small *UDF()*:

```
Public Function AnyMatch(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rTemp As Range
    AnyMatch = "NO"

    For Each r In r1
        v = r.Value
        Set rTemp = r2.Find(What:=v, After:=r2(1), LookAt:=xlPart)
        If rTemp Is Nothing Then
        Else
            AnyMatch = "YES"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=AnyMatch(A1:C1,H1:Z1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: sorry, but several people that use this xls file do not like to have macros enabled (some are MAC users), others worry about 'virus'

Comment: @DoowopDJ  Then use any posted non-VBA solution.

Comment: Where is the non-VBA solution in this post?

Comment: @DoowopDJ  You must wait for someone else to post an answer......a formula to accomplish this is beyond my abilities.

Comment: I have updated my example of the problem.  I hope that it is clear of what the problem is